# Return filename from path

Tags: c++

What did I do wrong here?

call

```
printf(filename(exename));
```

my function should return filename

```
const char* filename(const string& str)
{
  const char* path;
  size_t found;
  found=str.find_last_of("/\\");
  path = (str.substr(found+1)).c_str();

  cout << str.substr(found+1); // ------------> is name ok 

  printf("\n\n");
  printf(path); // ------------> is name not ok random numbers
  printf("\n\n");
  return  path; // ------------> is not ok random numbers
}
```

Comment: You should not use printf here, but fputs or puts, or possibly `printf( "%s", exename );`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Could you remind me why that is again?

Comment: If the filename contains formatting characters, bad things happen.  This is probably not an issue in your case, but it is wasteful to parse the string when it is not needed.

Comment: Why not use [`dirname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/dirname.html)?

Comment: @Vlad Because it doesn't return the file name.

Comment: @Tim: [`basename()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/basename.3.html) does. The point is — why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @Vlad Point taken. Similarly [boost::filesystem::path::filename()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-filename) can be used for a cross platform solution.

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko. DSP environment does not contain all c/c++ standard functions. so messing around  is sometimes required.

Comment: @Power-Mosfet If this is for a DSP you should reconsider using `std::string` altogether. `std::string::substr()` can throw exceptions which is a feature that is likely not supported by your environment if it doesn't come with a full C++ implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`str.substr(found+1)` returns a **temporary** `std::string`.
You call `c_str()` method on that *temporary* `std::string`, and assign the returned pointer to `path`.
When the temporary is destroyed (at the `;`), your path is pointing to garbage.

Make yourself a favor and use **C++** (not C mixed with C++), using robust string classes like `std::string` to store strings (instead of raw potentially-dangling `char*` pointers):

```
std::string FileName(const std::string& str)
{
  size_t found = str.find_last_of("/\\");
  std::string path = str.substr(found+1); // check that is OK
  return path;
}
```

Note also that your use of `path` variable name is confusing, since the function seems to return the file name (not the path).

A simpler rewrite (without the `path` variable):

```
std::string ExtractFileName(const std::string& fullPath)
{
  const size_t lastSlashIndex = fullPath.find_last_of("/\\");
  return fullPath.substr(lastSlashIndex + 1);
}


printf("Filename = %s\n", ExtractFileName("c:\\some\\dir\\hello.exe").c_str());
```

...or just use `cout` (which plays well with `std::string` and doesn't require `c_str()` method call to get a raw C string pointer like in C `printf()` function):

```
std::cout << ExtractFileName("c:\\some\\dir\\hello.exe");
```

Answer (score 5):

You are returning a pointer to memory that is held by a temporary `(str.substr(found+1)).c_str()`.  When the temporary goes out of scope, the memory could be overwritten at any time.

`str.substr(found+1)` is an expression that returns a `string`.  This object is a temporary value which will go away at the end of the execution of the expression that contains it.  With `.c_str()`, you are getting a pointer to memory controlled by this object.  After the object's lifetime, this pointer is no longer valid.

Try declaring `path` as a `string`, and having your function return a `string` instead of a pointer.

In general, you should avoid working with raw `char *` when you are also working with the `std::string`  class.  That means you should also avoid using `printf`; use the `std::iostream` classes instead.

Comment: Could you please explain further? What exactly is going out of scope and when?

Comment: However, the print inside the function `filename` should still produce reliable output, unless `substr` does not find a slash.

Comment: @WilliamPursell The printf insed the function is undefined behavior.  The expression `str.substr( found + 1 )` returns a temporary, which will be destructed at the end of the full expression.